# sqlalchemy easy way to insert or update?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sequence of new objects. They all look like similar to this:

Foo(pk_col1=x, pk_col2=y, val='bar')

Some of those are Foo that exist (i.e. only val differs from the row in the db)
and should generate update queries. The others should generate inserts.

I can think of a few ways of doing this, the best being:

```
pk_cols = Foo.table.primary_key.keys()
for f1 in foos:
    f2 = Foo.get([getattr(f1, c) for c in pk_cols])
    if f2 is not None:
        f2.val = f1.val # update
        # XXX do we need to do session.add(f2) 
        # (or at least keep f2 alive until after the commit?)
    else:
        session.add(f1) # insert

 session.commit()
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708762/sqlalchemy-insert-or-replace-equivalent or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330475/how-do-i-efficiently-do-a-bulk-insert-or-update-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: @Duffy - Not the same question as I actually need to distinguish in python the updates from the inserts, I can't do it at the database with a non-portable SQL extension.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you are after [new_obj = session.merge(obj)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging). This will merge an object in a detached state into the session if the primary keys match and will make a new one otherwise. So `session.save(new_obj)` will work for both insert and update.

Comment: ``session.save()`` doesn't seem to exist anymore in new versions of sqlalchemy.

Comment: I think it doesn't work for mysql. I tried it didn't work. Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy 1.1.10