# save_or_update using SQLalchemy 0.6

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

`save_or_update` has been removed in 0.6. Are there alternatives to use them in 0.6 and above?

I noticed the existence of the method `_save_or_update_state` for session objects, but there are no docs on this method.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382469/sqlalchemy-easy-way-to-insert-or-update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Michael Bayer answered this question :](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/msg/3f601d99992ba3c2)

> update(), save_or_update(), save() are
> all deprecated.  add() places an
> object in the session in all cases,
> using the persistence information
> already associated with the object to
> determine INSERT or UPDATE.   this
> means if you just make a new
> Foo(id=some id), that's transient -
> SQLAlchemy didn't load it.  It will be
> INSERTed.
>
> Keep in mind that the
> Session maintains an identity map of
> all unique  primary keys already
> loaded into memory, as well as the
> state which was  received from the
> database.  For this reason, you
> generally can't just put  an object in
> the session with some arbitrary data,
> and expect it to "take  the place" of
> the actual row that would be loaded by
> the transaction.  SQLAlchemy wouldn't
> know what to do with it since it has
> no idea what  changes have been made
> to this row versus what is already
> present.
>
> If you'd like to create a
> new Foo() with a primary key that may
> or may not  already exist in the
> database, you want to merge the state
> of that object  with one that is
> produced by the Session.  Use
> session.merge() for this  use case.
> this will load the existing object
> from the current  transaction, if any,
> and merge the state of your outside
> object with it,  returning the
> instance.  The instance you pass to it
> remains unchanged and  outside the
> session.

Answer (score 1):

`Session.merge()` works fine for both new and existing object. But you have to remember, that `merge()` *returns* object bound to the session as opposed to `add()` (and `save_or_update()` in old versions) which puts object passed as argument into the session. This behavior is required to insure there is a single object for each identity in the session.

Answer (score -1):

`session.merge()` will not work if you have your db setup as a master-slave, where you typically want to query from the slave, but write to the master. I have such a setup, and ended up re-querying from the master just before the writing, then using a `session.add()` if the data is indeed not there on the master.